# Content folder FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION

Tags: apex, content, libraries

Trying to create folder inside content library based on [this information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentfolder.htm).

As mentioned here I can do that, but when I am trying to set library id as ParentContentFolderId, I am getting an error.

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Parent Content Folder ID: id value of
>   incorrect type: 0581a0000008i6O: [ParentContentFolderId]

0581a0000008i6O is the id of existing library.

I don't understand the error or how to solve this.

Comment: cloud lover it'll help if you include your apex code.